# EC2 instance public ip address access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using windows server ec2 instance.. I was able to access the instance through the public ip normally but after I used codedeploy and deployed my application I get an error saying "access denied" (using port 80) and here is my inbound rules:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like your application didn't start up successfully after your deploy. You should login (RDP) to the server and see if there are error messages in the logs.

Comment: Receiving an "error saying access denied" would by definition mean your security groups are correctly allowing access.  Security group misconfigurations cause *timeouts*.

Comment: @MarkB I logged into the instance through RDP and the application is there but when I explore the default website it opens the folder containing the project itself and when I open the web page it opens giving me an error saying: "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue is with Outbound Rules. While the machine can get packets, it might not be able to respond back to the caller.

Comment: Security Groups are stateful which automatically allows response traffic regardless of any rules.

Comment: I have the outbound rule set also